# CAAnimation get live updates of animated properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-graphics, core-animation

I have added a `CAAnimation` to some view's layer, and it animates the view's `position`. While the animation runs, I want to animate an object in a OpenGL window. In order to do so, I have to somehow get live updates from the property I animate.

I tried

```
someView.layer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "position", options: nil, context: nil)
```

But I only get updates once the animatin completes. I also tried to add the observer to the presentation layer, without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: same here. Anybody has an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to observe (KVO) the transform of a CALayer during an CABasicAnimation but never worked for me, even trying on the PresentationLayer... The way I solved it in my situation was to use a CADisplayLink.

That will allow you to specify the frameTimeInterval you want the link to run with and each time it fires you can directly check on the transform of the layer you have been trying to get KVO updates from.

Works great for me.

So, something like this:

```
displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "foo")
displayLink?.frameInterval = 1
displayLink?.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
```

Inside foo() I would then check for the transform on the layer's presentationLayer() and then I would use the information as needed...